# How do I redirect output to cd?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, cd-command

Is it possible to redirect a command's output to `cd`? For example, I searched for a directory using `locate` and got the path to it. Now, instead of writing a `cd` path, can I redirect the `locate` output to `cd`?

I tried this:

```
$ locate Descargas | grep Descargas$
/home/oliver/Descargas
$ locate Descargas | grep Descargas$ | cd
$ locate Descargas | grep Descargas$ > cd
$ locate Descargas | grep Descargas$ < cd
/home/oliver/Descargas
$
```

No luck. This probably isn't particularly useful, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want command substitution, not redirection:

```
cd "$(locate Descargas | grep -F 'Descargas$')"
```

The bits between the `$(` and the `)` are run as a command and the output (stripped of any final newline) is substituted into the overall command.

This can also be done with ‘back ticks’ (“`”):

```
cd "`locate Descargas | grep -F 'Descargas$'`"
```

The dollar-paren syntax is generally preferred because it is easier to deal with in nested situations:

```
# contrived
cd "$(grep '^dir: ' "$(locate interesting-places | head -1)" | sed 's/^[^ ]*//')"
```