# What kind of pipe will work to enter random data into a compiled program for option 1 and option 2 at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to pipe random data into a program that is suppose to predict the next correct number. I want to run a infinite loop pipe for option 1 which leads to option 2 with another option with c to continue. The reason for this is for the AI to be trained in predicting patterns found in random generated numbers.

## NOTE: When, I say option 1 and option 2 i mean by selecting option 1 it will display the following options "enter number 1 and enter number 2.

This is what the program looks like in the shell.

```
Select your choice.

1. Enter the newest number.

2. Find a new number.


-------------------------------------------------------------------

Select your choice.

1. Enter the newest number.

2. Find a new number.


 Enter number 1. 

 Enter number 2. 

 Enter c to continue or 0 to quite
```

Pipes that I tried to get to work, but failed.

```
./RNGAI | echo "1" | shuf -i 1-26 -n1 | echo "2" | shuf -i 1-26 -n1 | echo "c" | ./RNGAI
./RNGAI | echo "1" | echo $((RANDOM%10))| ./RNGAI & echo "2" | echo $((RANDOM%10)) & echo "c"
```

## I have an error after trying some pipes. The pipes do technically work, however the RNGAI program throws errors show -nan every time it runs its loop with the pipe. Here are the pipes and scripts I tried to run

```
while true
do
echo 1
echo $ od -A n -N 2 -t u2  /dev/random
echo 2
echo $ od -A n -N 2 -t u2  /dev/random
echo c
done | ./RNGAI
```

Here are the pipes

```
 while :; do printf "%s\n" 1  seq 1 26 | sort -R | head -n 1 2  seq 1 26     | sort -R | head -n 1 c; done | ./RNGAI
 while :; do printf "%s\n" 1 od -A n -N 2 -t u2  /dev/random 2 $od -A n -N 2 -t u2  /dev/random c; done | ./RNGAI
 while :; do printf "%s\n" 1 shuf -i 1-26 -n1 2 shuf -i 1-26 -n1 c; done | ./RNGAI
```

## Error the RNGAI program throws

```
   Select your choice.

   1. Enter the newest number.

   2. Find a new number.

      Enter number 1. 
      Enter number 2. 
      -nan
      -nan
       Enter c to continue or 0 to quite 
       Enter number 1. 
       Enter number 2. 
       -nan
       -nan
```

Comment: Good luck on the mission of "predicting patterns found in random generated numbers."!

Comment: @JeffSchaller if the source is a pseudo-RNG, it's actually a good exercise. That's the reason why [cryptographically secure RNGs are so important](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449594/2072269) - all pseudo-RNGs become predictable given a sufficiently long history.

Comment: This might be useful in cracking encryption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect output to cd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-cd)

Comment: Your pipes are meaningless. If you want to use the output of a command as argument to another command, use command substitution. See linked post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
while true
do
    echo 1
    echo $((RANDOM % 10))
    echo 2
    echo $((RANDOM % 10))
    echo c
done | ./RNGAI
```

Or more concisely:

```
while :; do printf "%s\n" 1 $((RANDOM % 10)) 2 $((RANDOM % 10)) c; done | ./RNGAI
```

You want to pipe data into a program, then the input comes *before* the pipe:

```
<source of input> | <command that uses the input>
```

Comment: The pipes work, but the program is throwing errors. It says -nan every time when it is in loop. I even tried different commands to generate random numbers.  Here is an example of what I tried to run in a script.  while true
do
    echo 1
    echo $ od -A n -N 2 -t u2  /dev/random
    echo 2
    echo $ od -A n -N 2 -t u2  /dev/random
    echo c
done | ./RNGAI

Comment: @TravisWells edit the question to include the actual code